# Binding for Grid

Tags: wpf

I have 10*2 (10 rows, 2 columns)Grid control. Second column contains a shape control for each row. For data, I have a list of object of a class containing lets say an integer member. I want to change color of a shape according to value of integer (I can use "Converter" for that). My question is how to bind ellipse Fill property to that of source property (int value) from list. Note, I am using grid not listbox or listview in veiw and simple list (not observable collection).

Comment: Can't you create a ValueConverter to convert from from int to Fill?

Comment: Yes. conversion part is not a problem. I want to know how binding should be implemented.

Comment: if you want to change Shape's color just change bind to [Fill](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.fill(v=vs.110).aspx) as @maillard said, and specify converter that will convert int to brush.
`<Shape Fill={Binding YouValue, Converter=YouIntToBrushConverter/>`

Answer (score 0):

Change your grid for itemsControl, must be something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="10" Columns="2"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Shape Fill="{Binding YourIntValue, Converter=YourIntToBrushConverter}">
                    YourData
                </Shape>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```